# Ambiguous reference to array fields in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I'm new to pyspark. I'd like to be able to read values from my kafka topic. To do so, I've created a schema for messages in my topic.

Here is example message in my kafka topic:

```
{
   "action": "string",
   "id": "string",
   "epoch": "long",
   "entity": {
       "type": "string",
       "sources": [{
           "items": [
               {"identifier": "string"},
               {"identifier": "string"},
           ] 
       }]
   }
}
```

Here is my schema:

```
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- epoch: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sources: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- identifier: string (nullable = true)
```

However, I get an error when trying to select the fields I'm interested in.

```
value_df = df.select(
    from_json(col("value").cast("string"), Schema).alias("value"), 
)

explode_df = value_df.select(
    "value.id", 
    "value.action", 
    "value.epoch",
    "value.entity.type",
    "value.entity.sources.items.identifier", 
)

explode_df.printSchema()
```

This is the error I get:

```
An error was encountered:
Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(entity,StructType(StructField(type,StringType,true)),true), StructField(entity,StructType(StructField(sources,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(items,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(identifier,StringType,true)),true),true)),true),true)),true)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1671, in select
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(entity,StructType(StructField(type,StringType,true)),true), StructField(entity,StructType(StructField(sources,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(items,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(identifier,StringType,true)),true),true)),true),true)),true)
```

I believe this is because `sources` and `items` are both arrays. Is there a way to read arrays into a df using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have `entity` twice in your schema, that is the ambiguous reference.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted! Now I get this error :( `cannot resolve '`value`.`entity`.`sources`.`items`['identifier']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''identifier'' is of string type.`

Comment: How did you handle this, where we have sample xml tag twice?  I am facing the same issue.  any help or pointer would help pls